# need max value timestamps in pig latin script

Tags: apache-pig

Input data is as below:

```
(1,a,1,2)
(2,a,2,4)
(5,a,7,5)
(6,a,3,1)
(8,a,4,3)
(3,a,8,6)
(7,a,5,8)
(4,a,6,7)
```

Script as below:

```
a =  load '/tmp/data/data' using PigStorage(',') as (timestamp:chararray,constant:chararray,data1:chararray,data2:chararray);
b = FOREACH (GROUP a BY(constant)){
ord4 = ORDER a BY timestamp DESC;
top4 = LIMIT ord4 1;
GENERATE FLATTEN(top4),MAX(a.data1) as data,MAX(a.data2) as data2;}
g4 = FOREACH b GENERATE top4::timestamp AS timestamp,
                   top4::constant AS constant,
                   top4::data1 AS curr_data1,
                   top4::data2 AS curr_data2,
                   data1 as data1,
                   data2 as data2;
dump g4;
```

Output is as below:

```
(8,a,4,3,8,8)
```

Still need timestamp of data1 which is 3  and data2 which is 7.

like below:

```
(8,a,4,3,8,8,3,7)
```

Could you please advise how that can be achived?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have only provided 6 fields in relation **g4** so is the output ((8,a,4,3),8,8)) .

Please be more specific when you say

*Still need timestamp of data1 which is 3 and data2 which is 7.*

What exactly is expected in the last two fields.

Comment: I am doing a max on data1 and data2 which is 8 and 8 and i also need the timetsmaps of that which is 3 and 7.  Which means in relation g4 i need to add timestamps for dataa and data2.